# extract js data from a web page using scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I am crawling a web page using scrapy.

Now there's some data in a script tag. I got all data in script tag using xpath and looks like this.

```
 <script>
 some data

 abc.xyz=[["mohit","gupta","456123"]];

 some data
 </script>
```

I want data in `abc.xyz` but I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression `abc.xyz=(.*?);` for extracting the variable value. Also, if you want to make a python list from it, you can use [literal_eval()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

text = """<script>
 some data

 abc.xyz=[["mohit","gupta","456123"]];

 some data
 </script>"""

value = re.search('abc.xyz=(.*?);', text).group(1)
print value, type(value)

value = literal_eval(value)
print value, type(value)
```

prints:

```
[["mohit","gupta","456123"]] <type 'str'>
[['mohit', 'gupta', '456123']] <type 'list'>
```

Comment: Is there any method to handle javascript data..??
because my problem is different.

I want to iterate over values of abc.xyz

Comment: @user2779095 could you show the actual `<script>` tag contents?